# jQuery AJAX .post doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem using AJAX `.post` in Internet Explorer. In all other browsers, this works fine (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera).
On the [login page of my website](http://panel.irgs.ir), using `.post` doesn't work.

Below is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#even tr:even").addClass("even");
    $('#login_loader').hide();
    $("#login_form_submit").click(function() {
        $('#login_form_submit').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#login_loader').fadeIn(200);
        $('#login_group').slideUp(500);
        $('#logout_hint').slideUp(500);
        $('#login_contact_form').slideUp(500);
        $.post("action/login.php?act=login", {
            username: $('#login_username').val(),
            password: $('#login_password').val(),
            captcha: $('#login_captcha').val()
        }, function(response) {

            setTimeout("finishAjax('login_group', '" + escape(response) + "')", 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
    $('#login_loader').slideUp(300);
    $('#login_contact_form').fadeIn(300);
    $('#' + id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#' + id).fadeIn(500);
    $('#login_form_submit').attr('disabled', false);
    $("#captchaImg").attr("src");
}​
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does your server receive any request from IE when you try this? Perhaps change the relative URI to an absolute one (i.e. one that starts with a forward slash)?

Comment: Well, what does "doesn't work" mean? Use IE developer tools of Fiddler2 to see what is on the network, then work from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing this from a file or from a web server? If you're trying to do this from a file, I suggest you install a web server and try again.

Edit: what exactly doesn't work? When I submit the form, a POST request is being sent and there are no errors in the console.[image: Debugging screenshot]

What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: The Login Page have Problem with IE7 and below

Comment: I will take a look at it, but have you considered not supporting IE < 8, as users can easily upgrade their installations?

Comment: The post request is sent normally for me, and I get an error page that «presumably» my password is incorrect.

Comment: yes in IE 8 and above , the response from requested page is ok , but on below IE8 have Problem !!?

Answer (score 2):

IE is notorious for it's aggressive caching, have you ruled out this possibility?

If not, try to add the following line in your html

`<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});</script><![endif]-->`

Or you could set it on a per request basis if it turns out that this was it after all